# google analytics not showing numeric values

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to send an event (with a numeric value) to google analytics but the numeric value is not being shown in google analytics dashboard:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
 m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
 })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XX-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'test',
    eventAction: 'visit_on_page',
    eventLabel: 'label2',
    eventValue: Math.round(Math.random()*100)
  });
```

[image]

Comment: can you add an image of what is being shown?

Comment: @DaImTo I attached a screenshot - sorry for the foreign language (I did't manage to change it to english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find event value in Events report (not in Real time report).